# Making sense of findings from Josephus' problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say we have positive integer n. If n is even, we take $\frac{n}{2}$ . If n is odd, we take $\frac{n+1}{2}$ , repeating until it reaches 1. Each time this step occurs, we denote it at a turn and we find out in which turns it is odd (excluding 1). E.g. for 9, 9 - 5 - 3 - 2 - 1. It's odd at turns 1, 2, 3. Is there a way (probably with regards to binary powers) to easily figure out in which turns the process will be odd?

Comment: In base 2, the process for 9 rewrites as : 1001, 101, 11, 10, 1

For  164 : 10100100, 1010010, 101001, 10101, 1011, 110, 11, 10, 1; Note that an number is odd iff it ends with a 1 in base 2

Comment: I think @Astyx is leading you down the right path. It looks like oddness occurs when the last digit is 1, and looking at the number you can predict this based on the number of 0's between 1's

Comment: It makes sense, but this is as good as writing out the entire process in decimal and seeing in which step it ends in an odd number. Edit: @KitterCatter I thought so too with my remark on binary powers, but I haven't gotten anything concrete.

Comment: Take a look at the position of the 0's after the first (lowest power of 2) 1. Each of those will be an odd digit in the sequence.

Comment: This is because it happens not to be 1. If it were 1, the value on its left would go up by 1. And the process begins again. What were you describing? (Successive) summation of +1 in binary. Edit: Have an idea though from this. I'll work it out..

Comment: @KitterCatter Sorry I misread your comment. Looks like this way works. Any 0 on the left of the first 1 will be odd, with the 1 inclusive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's take for instance the number 110010110100 (=3252) in base 2:**
Go from right to left.

The first appearance of 1 is in third place, so turn 3 is the first odd turn.

Once 1 has appeared once, every appearance of a 1 will be even and every appearance of 0 will be odd. Here, turns 3, 4, 7, 8 and 9 are odd and the others are even.

**Second example : 1001010101110 (=4782)**
Odd turns are 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 (and 14, 15, 16, ...) since there are zeroes on positions 1, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 (and 14, 15, ...) and that the first appearance of 1 is on position 2

**Last example just to make sure it is clear : 10010100100101111000000 (=4869056)**
There are zeroes on positions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22 (and 24, 25, ...) and the first appearance of 1 is on position 7, thus odd turns will be 7, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, ...